# how to get xtragrid focused cell's entity property

Tags: xtragrid

I want to get xtragrid focused cell entity property. Because of this :

I'm trying to get, focused cell isnull property, for this i need to get focused cell entityproperty

I tried to get object like  (EdmScalarPropertyAttribute)gird.focusedrowvalue, but i got null value exception

How can i do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get the RowHandle of the XtraGridView is this:

int rowHandle = gridView1.GetSelectedRows()[0]

hope it helps, and if you are trying to get the value of the cell you can use the following code

object obj = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.GetSelectedRows()[0], gridView1.FocusedColumn.FieldName);